# Leitura de páginas HTML com .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core

Seguinte, tenho um código que realiza leitura de determinada página web:

```
private string GetCodePage()
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(URL);
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

    var codePage = reader.ReadToEnd();

    reader.Close();
    response.Close();

    return codePage;
}
```

Estou tentando fazer o mesmo código com .NET Core, mas as classes mudaram, por exemplo, não existe mais o método `WebRequest.GetResponse`.

Alguem sabe como fazer leitura de paginas html pelo DotNet Core?

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "leitura" de página web? Salvar o fonte da página no disco?

Comment: Possuo um robô que obtem informações através do fonte das páginas. Se a solução for baixar o fonte, não tem problema, pois posso ler como um file.

Answer (score 4):

Você vai ter que usar a nova classe `HttpClient` em **`System.Net.Http`**, que está disponível [no Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http/).

Um exemplo bem simples de como usar:

```
using(var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = await client.GetStringAsync(URL);
    //Existem outras opções aliém do GetStringAsync, aí você precisa explorar a classe
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver com o seguinte código:

```
    private string GetCodePage()
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var response = httpClient.GetAsync(URL).Result;
        return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
```

Comment: Cuidado com classes que implementem `IDisposable`. Você pode ter problemas ignorando o `Dispose` de `HttpClient`.